# Is $AGL(3,2)$ self-normalizing in $S_8$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, permutations

Let $AGL(3,2)$ be a group of all affine permutations consisting of maps
$$
x \to Ax + b,
$$
where $x$ and $b$ are vectors of length $3$ over $GF(2)$ and $A$ is an invertible $3\times 3$ matrix over $GF(2)$. Using some numeration of vectors we can consider $AGL(3,2)$ as a subgroup of $S_8$. My experimets with computer algebra system Sage have shown that normaliser of $AGL(3,2)$ in $S_8$ is equal to $AGL(3,2)$. But I can not prove this. Can somebody help me with hints or full solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, computations with Sage *is* a full solution, in my opinion. A better phrase for what you're asking for is an easy proof.

Here is a proof that in general $\mathrm{AGL}(n, p)$ is self-normalizing in $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbf{F}_p^n) \cong S_{p^n}$.

Let $V \le \mathrm{Sym}(\mathbf{F}_p^n)$ be the group of all $p^n$ translations, so $V \cong \mathbf{F}_p^n$. Then $G =\mathrm{AGL}(n, p)$ is the normalizer of $V$. On the other hand $G / V \cong \mathrm{GL}(n, p)$ and $\mathrm{GL}(n, p)$ has no normal $p$-subgroup, so $V$ is the largest normal $p$-subgroup of $G$ and therefore characteristic in $G$, so $N(G) \le N(V)$. Therefore $G \le N(G) \le N(V) = G$, so $G = N(G)$.

Comment: Several independent computations using several pieces of software can be a strong hint that something is true. But sage, just like anything, has bugs. I've run across quite a few bugs in mathematical software that made it give wrong results.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Proofs written by humans can also have bugs, but we still call them proofs. Whether a proof is correct or not, while important, is a different question from whether something in principle is a proof.

Comment: I'd say that we will more and more reserve the word proof to refer to *things* that enlighten us about the truth of a claim — like Derek's argument. Enlightment is much more resistent to bugs than mere calculation, mostly because it is flexible and leverages the knowledge of the reader of the proof. A calculation in sage — and this comes from some one who computes literally all the time with computers — is not close to that.

Comment: Obviously some proofs are more informative than others, and we tend to prefer the ones that teach us stuff. But in this case we are calculating something specific about a subgroup of $S_8$ and it is perfectly fine to check this on a computer. As for your "more and more" claim, I doubt that very much. It would be rather eccentric to say that the four color theorem has not been proved, for example. We as a community in 2023 are pretty accustomed to proof-by-computer, and taking the blanket view that computers are unreliable is not a good idea today.

Comment: Why is $G$ the normalizer of $V$? I see that the claim boils down to proving that if a permutation $P$ is such that $P^{-1}(Px+\alpha) - x$ depends only on $\alpha$, then $P$ is necessarily affine. However, I don't see how to prove a claim like that.

Comment: @SaliniMendisi I will use your notation. By composing $P$ with a translation we may assume $P(0) = 0$. Then since $P^{-1}(P(x) + \alpha) - x$ depends only on $\alpha$, it must be its value at $x=0$, which is $P^{-1}(\alpha)$, so we get the relation $P^{-1}(P(x) + \alpha) - x = P^{-1}(\alpha)$. This holds for any $\alpha$. Let $\alpha = P(y)$ and rearrange to get $P(x+y) = P(x) + P(y)$, so $P$ is a linear map, which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: @SaliniMendisi In general if $V$ is a regular permutation group (simply transitive) then its normalizer is $V \rtimes \mathrm{Aut}(V)$. The proof is essentially the same but generalized. Let $N$ be the normalizer of $V$. Since $V$ is transitive, $N = VN_\omega$ where $N_\omega$ is the stabilizer of a point $\omega$. Let $C = C_{N_\omega}(V)$. Then $C$ stabilizes a point and commutes with a transitive group so $C = 1$. Hence the map $N_\omega \to \mathrm{Aut}(V)$ induced by conjugation is injective, and it is clearly surjective.

Comment: @SeanEberhard, thank you for an elegant solution!

Comment: @SeanEberhard Hmmm, one more question - why is $N_\omega \to \text{Aut}(V)$ surjective?

Comment: @SaliniMendisi Let $\phi \in \mathrm{Aut}(V)$. Since we can identify the domain with $V$ we can consider the permutation defined by $\phi$. More formally, define a permutation $\pi$ of the domain by $\pi(v \omega) = \phi(v) \omega$ for $v \in V$. Then $\pi$ normalizes $V$ because $\pi(vv'\omega) = \phi(vv') \omega = \phi(v) \phi(v') \omega = \phi(v) \pi(v' \omega)$ for $v, v' \in V$: this equation implies that translation by $v$ conjugated by $\pi$ is the same as translation by $\phi(v)$. Hence $\pi \in N_\omega$ and it maps to $\phi$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard I think I see. By the way, why do you need $v'$ instead of just taking $v'=1$? Is it to ensure that $\pi vv'$ and $\phi(v)\pi v'$ are both in $V$ so that you can conclude $\pi vv' \cdot \omega = \phi(v)\pi v' \cdot \omega$ implies $\pi vv'= \phi(v)\pi v'$?

Comment: @SaliniMendisi The reason is that $\omega$ is just one point of the domain, and the whole domain is parameterized by $V$ in the manner $\Omega = \{v\omega : v \in V\}$. Therefore to check that the permutations $\pi v$ and $\phi(v) \pi$ are the same we need to test them on a generic point $v'\omega$.

Answer (score 3):

The affine subgroup $N$ of ${\rm AGL}(3,2)$, is elementary abelian of order $8$, and it is characteristic in ${\rm AGL}(3,2)$ because it is the largest normal $2$-subgroup.

Since $N$ is abelian and acts regularly, it is self-centralizing in $S_8$ (I'll leave you to prove that), so $N_{S_8}(N)/C_{S_8}(N)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(N)$, which is isomorphic to ${\rm GL}(3,2)$ (because $N$ can be regarded as a $3$-dimensional vector space over ${\mathbb F}_2$).

So, since since the whole of ${\rm GL}(3,2)$ is induced by conjugation in ${\rm AGL}(3,2)$, we must have $N_{S_8}({\rm AGL}(3,2)) = N_{S_8}(N) = {\rm AGL}(3,2)$.

Comment: thank you, very much!

Comment: How do you prove that $N$ is the largest normal $2$-subgroup of $\mathrm{AGL}(3,2)$?

Comment: @SaliniMendisi $G/N \cong {\rm GL}(3,2)$, which is simple and has no nontrivial normal $2$-subgroup.